# Reading CSV header and saving with Dataflow Beam on Python

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

How to read the first line and store header data in Apache Beam Python?

Comment: Could please add little more details to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/interactive/examples/UsCovidDataExample.ipynb). See how the `UsCovidDataCsvReader` parses the input.

The basic ideas are

- read the header and build a schema from it
- read the file with `skip_header_lines=1`
- parse the input with the schema to build a PCollection